# Segurando teclas no terminal

Tags: c, entrada-de-dados

Olá, no meu Ubuntu 16.04, no momento da execução de um programa em C(assim como no sublime), quando eu aperto uma tecla, fica repetindo a mesma tecla até soltar. Até aí tudo bem.
Mas se eu não solto essa tecla e eu aperto outra tecla, essa outra fica repetindo e é como se eu tivesse soltado a primeira tecla.

Há como verificar se as duas teclas estão pressionadas simultaneamente?

Answer (score 0):

Existem teclas e teclas. Voce nao consegue ler (através de um `scanf`) por exemplo a combinacao das teclas `A` e `B` pressionadas ao mesmo tempo, pois nao e um caractere, simplesmente nao existe `AB`.

Para usar alguma combinacao de tecla voce vai ter que usar as seguintes: `CTRL`, `ALT` e `SHIFT`, combinadas com alguma tecla de caractere, ou seja, os caracteres de A até Z.

Note que todos atalhos dos programas sao o `CTRL + (A-Z)`, `ALT + (A-Z)` ou `SHIFT + (A-Z)` também é comum usar as teclas `F(1-12)` (Functions keys).

Na realidade algumas combinacoes dessas teclas emite um caractere nao imprimivel, um caractere de controle que o teu software podera usar para executar alguma funcao especifica.

Compile esse codigo e veja a diferenca do valor nas combinacoes das teclas com `CTRL`, `ALT` e `SHIFT`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char key;

    printf("press any key:>");
    scanf("%c", &key);
    printf("key pressed:>%X \n", key);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Certo, abaixo tem meu repositório no github:
https://github.com/CarlosAdir/C-Programs/tree/master/Tutoriais/Arquivos_kbhitgetch.
Uma pasta acima, tem o tutorial kbhitgetch.pdf, explica essa parte de entrada de dado.
Mas compile e execute o código 8-extras.c e segure uma tecla. Ele mostra cada tecla apertada.
Mas a questão seria: como saber se duas teclas estão pressionadas, se existe alguma configuração específica do terminado por exemplo. O código compilou e executou no Ubuntu 16.04 perfeitamente.

Comment: Consegui compilar tranquilo o codigo, mas eu acho que nao entendi bem ainda a sua pergunta. Voce queria **detectar** quando eu _pressiono e seguro_ a tecla X, a deixo pressionada e depois aperto a tecla Y? Seria essa a _deteccao_ que voce esta buscando?

Comment: Sim. Quando eu pressiono e segura a tecla X, começa a aparecer vários "Você apertou X" e se você solta para de aparecer."Você apertou X". Mas se eu não soltar X e pressionar e segurar Y, para de aparecer "Você apertou X" e passa a aparecer "Você apertou Y" várias vezes, como se eu tivesse soltado o X.
O que busco é saber quando duas teclas estão pressionadas ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Entendi, eu nunca gosto de dizer que nao tem como fazer porque no mundo da informatica sempre tem um jeito. Mas note o seguinte: Quando voce aperta e segura a tecla X, depois aperta e segura a tecla Y sem soltar a tecla X, solte a tecla Y e veja que o programa ja nao detecta mais que a tecla X esta sendo pressionada. Portanto, com base nesse comportamento, parece que no momento que voce aperta a Y 'mata' a X.

Comment: É, vou procurar um pouco mais sobre isso. Obrigado!